# dial tcp: lookup goproxy.cn: i/o timeout when build my own Docker image

Tags: docker, proxy, goproxy

I am building a Docker image of my own with VPN connected
I consistently encounter the error :dial tcp: lookup goproxy.cn: i/o timeout.
I searched for the answer , seems like I need a proxy in order to access the github and download go pakage, which I have added 'PROXY' env in my Dockerfile , but still I consistently encounter this 'dial tcp: lookup goproxy.cn: i/o timeout ' error

```
go: github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery@v1.8.0: Get "https://goproxy.cn/github.com/%21puerkito%21bio/goquery/@v/v1.8.0.mod": dial tcp: lookup goproxy.cn: i/o timeout
```

Here are my Dockerfile and Make file
Docker file :

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE_ARCH="amd64"

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_ARCH}/golang:buster AS build

# blocking github workaround
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct
ENV GOSUMDB="sum.golang.google.cn"

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -qq build-essential devscripts dh-make dh-systemd && \
    mkdir -p /build/debian && \
    mkdir /pkg/

ADD . /src

CMD ["/src/packaging/debian/build.sh"]
```

Here is my Makefile , I am 'make debian':

```
APP          := miniflux
DOCKER_IMAGE := miniflux/miniflux
VERSION      := $(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
COMMIT       := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
BUILD_DATE   := `date +%FT%T%z`
LD_FLAGS     := "-s -w -X 'miniflux.app/version.Version=$(VERSION)' -X 'miniflux.app/version.Commit=$(COMMIT)' -X 'miniflux.app/version.BuildDate=$(BUILD_DATE)'"
PKG_LIST     := $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
DB_URL       := postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/miniflux_test?sslmode=disable
DEB_IMG_ARCH := amd64

export PGPASSWORD := postgres

.PHONY: \
    miniflux \
    linux-amd64 \
    linux-arm64 \
    linux-armv7 \
    linux-armv6 \
    linux-armv5 \
    linux-x86 \
    darwin-amd64 \
    darwin-arm64 \
    freebsd-amd64 \
    freebsd-x86 \
    openbsd-amd64 \
    openbsd-x86 \
    netbsd-x86 \
    netbsd-amd64 \
    windows-amd64 \
    windows-x86 \
    build \
    run \
    clean \
    test \
    lint \
    integration-test \
    clean-integration-test \
    docker-image \
    docker-image-distroless \
    docker-images \
    rpm \
    debian \
    debian-packages

miniflux:
    @ go build -buildmode=pie -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP) main.go

linux-amd64:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-amd64 main.go

linux-arm64:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-arm64 main.go

linux-armv7:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv7 main.go

linux-armv6:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=6 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv6 main.go

linux-armv5:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-armv5 main.go

darwin-amd64:
    @ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-darwin-amd64 main.go

darwin-arm64:
    @ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-darwin-arm64 main.go

freebsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-amd64 main.go

openbsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=openbsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-openbsd-amd64 main.go

windows-amd64:
    @ GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-windows-amd64 main.go

build: linux-amd64 linux-arm64 linux-armv7 linux-armv6 linux-armv5 darwin-amd64 darwin-arm64 freebsd-amd64 openbsd-amd64 windows-amd64

# NOTE: unsupported targets
netbsd-amd64:
    @ GOOS=netbsd GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-netbsd-amd64 main.go

linux-x86:
    @ GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-linux-x86 main.go

freebsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-x86 main.go

netbsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=netbsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-netbsd-x86 main.go

openbsd-x86:
    @ GOOS=openbsd GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-freebsd-x86 main.go

windows-x86:
    @ GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -ldflags=$(LD_FLAGS) -o $(APP)-windows-x86 main.go

run:
    @ LOG_DATE_TIME=1 go run main.go -debug

clean:
    @ rm -f $(APP)-* $(APP) $(APP)*.rpm $(APP)*.deb

test:
    go test -cover -race -count=1 ./...

lint:
    golint -set_exit_status ${PKG_LIST}

integration-test:
    psql -U postgres -c 'drop database if exists miniflux_test;'
    psql -U postgres -c 'create database miniflux_test;'
    go build -o miniflux-test main.go

    DATABASE_URL=$(DB_URL) \
    ADMIN_USERNAME=admin \
    ADMIN_PASSWORD=test123 \
    CREATE_ADMIN=1 \
    RUN_MIGRATIONS=1 \
    DEBUG=1 \
    ./miniflux-test >/tmp/miniflux.log 2>&1 & echo "$$!" > "/tmp/miniflux.pid"
    
    while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do sleep 1; done
    go test -v -tags=integration -count=1 miniflux.app/tests

clean-integration-test:
    @ kill -9 `cat /tmp/miniflux.pid`
    @ rm -f /tmp/miniflux.pid /tmp/miniflux.log
    @ rm miniflux-test
    @ psql -U postgres -c 'drop database if exists miniflux_test;'

docker-image:
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) -f packaging/docker/alpine/Dockerfile .

docker-image-distroless:
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) -f packaging/docker/distroless/Dockerfile .

docker-images:
    docker buildx build \
        --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm/v6 \
        --file packaging/docker/alpine/Dockerfile \
        --tag $(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(VERSION) \
        --push .

debian:
    @ docker build \
        --build-arg BASE_IMAGE_ARCH=$(DEB_IMG_ARCH) \
        -t $(DEB_IMG_ARCH)/miniflux-deb-builder \
        -f packaging/debian/Dockerfile \
        --network=host \
        .
    @ docker run --rm \
        -v ${PWD}:/pkg $(DEB_IMG_ARCH)/miniflux-deb-builder
```